# How to configure Execute SQL Script in install4j for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, install4j

I am trying to configure an Execute SQL Script from install4j in order to crate a database schema, but that Script/Item fails.

Here are the current settings:

- JDBC Driver class name: DriverManager
- JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/
- User: root
- Password: password
- SQL SCRIPT:

> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS videos;
>
> GRANT USAGE ON *.* to videos_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '123password';
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON videos.* TO videos_user@localhost;
>
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

This at the moment is failing. I think the issue is that I need to add the JDBC driver JAR file. But I don't know where to get it and what class to add in the Driver class name.

I know this migh be a "noob" questions, but I am really stuck at this point.

Thank you!

Comment: I've added the driver. But I'm still having errors.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

- I downloaded the connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
- JDBC Driver class name should be com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- URL should be jdbc:mysql://localhost

Answer (score 0):

Add the JDBC driver JAR on the "Installer->Custom Code & Resources" step.

Comment: Where do i find it? what's the class name?